# Information and entaglement via determination of the first's system state with interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, measurements

Could we have entangled systems (microscopical or macroscopical) and construct a way of altering the state of one of the two entangled parts (let's say by Alice) via interaction and thus making the second measurement (Bob) be an information measurement defined by the first or would this destroy entanglement?

To be more specific:

If I can determine the state of a system via interaction (and that's the only reason I mentioned macroscopic entangled systems), and this system is entangled with another system, then when a measurement is made on the second system, would not the result be determined by the state of the first system? Is something like that possible?

Comment: what was the previous question before editing ?

Comment: @igael   The changes by editing didn't change the question. However, I didn't down vote your answer.

Comment: Ok , sorry. But you are free to downvote, it's the rule :)